# Kernel estimation of log-pdf

Tags: r

It's easy to plot a kernel estimate for the probability density function (pdf) of a random variable given an observation vector via:

```
plot(density(x))
```

I would like to do the same but for the log-pdf (log of the probability density function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
d <- density(x)
plot(d$x, log(d$y), type="l")
```

or maybe you'd prefer

```
plot(d, log="y")
```

Comment: The first piece of code is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.