# ggplot2 logdensity kernel estimation

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

What is the best way to achieve the same result as:
[Kernel estimation of log-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825186/kernel-estimation-of-log-pdf)

using **ggplot2** instead of base graphics? I would like to do it with something similar to `stat_density` as otherwise things get quickly complicated when combined with faceting etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

x = rnorm(100)

dev.new(width=4, height=4)
qplot(x, stat='density', geom='line') + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just assign `dlog_y= log(density(x)$y)` and call gglplot with that as your y-variable?

```
x = rnorm(100); dlog_y= log()
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
qplot(x = density(x)$x, y=dlog_y)
```